# What do "For each project, FCM allows 2500 connections in parallel" mean in FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does this mean that I can only have 2500 active tokens ?
How many tokens can I have per project ?

Please can anyone hep me out not able to find answers to these.

Reference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling

Comment: Also poted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/o3e3dc/what_do_for_each_project_fcm_allows_2500/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented limit for the number of tokens you can have for a project. Successful projects have many millions of tokens, and this is not a concern for FCM.

The limit you picked from the documentation applies to XMPP connections, which are fairly uncommon these days.

Comment: Thank you Frank so much. I have one more question is their a limit on number of messages per day

Comment: Thank you that helps I have accepted your answer